# How to know the client whether 2D or 3D inside XServer(Xorg)

Tags: linux

In X windowing system is there a way to know that any particular client is 2D or 3D?
Any structure in XORG side with a parameter by which this decision can be made?

There is a structure _Client which contains the information about the client but I dont know if any parameter of this structure can be used to make this decision.

Please help if anyone is aware of this.

Thanks

Comment: What does a 3D client means to you? Is it about OpenGL? It might go to 3D after a while!! Why are you asking??